# Required: Variable; Found: Value in a Switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

ok guys, I'm lost on this one. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double weight;
    double newWeight;
    int planet;

    System.out.println("1. Mercury");
    System.out.println("2. Venus");
    System.out.println("3. Earth");
    System.out.println("4. Mars");
    System.out.println("5. Jupiter");
    System.out.println("6. Saturn");
    System.out.println("7. Uranus");
    System.out.println("8. Neptune");
    System.out.println("9. Pluto");
    System.out.println("                   ");
    System.out.println("Select a planet from above: ");
    planet = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
    weight = input.nextInt();

    switch(newWeight) {
        case 1: (3.724 / 9.8) * weight = newWeight; break;
        case 2: (8.918 / 9.8) * weight = newWeight; break;
        case 3: (9.8 / 9.8) * weight = newWeight; break;
        case 4: (3.724 / 9.8) * weight = newWeight; break;
        case 5: (24.892 / 9.8) * weight = newWeight; break;
        case 6: (10.584 / 9.8) * weight = newWeight; break; 
        case 7: (8.918 / 9.8) * weight = newWeight; break;
        case 8: (11.662 / 9.8) * weight = newWeight; break;
        case 9: (1.622 / 9.8) * weight = newWeight; break;
    }
    System.out.print("Your weight on " + planet + "is: " + newWeight);
}
```

EDIT*****: ok figured out what was wrong, weight was an int and newWeight was a double. But now the final line `"System.out.print("your weight on " + planet + "is: " + newWeight);`

It says `"variable newWeight might not have been initialized".` If it's not one thing, its another.

Comment: You're not helping us at all. Give us some context. What are you trying to accomplish? Where are you stuck? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Your assignment statements are the wrong way around in that switch statement.

Comment: Pluto is not a planet...

Comment: haha according to google a planet is a "a celestial body moving in an elliptical orbit around a star." so i guess that would make Pluto a planet? And i think it's a dwarf planet now.

Answer (score 1):

The left hand side of the assignment operator should be an lvalue, not an expression, change

```
     (1.622 / 9.8) * weight = newWeight
```

to

```
        newWeight = (1.622 / 9.8) * weight
```

Comment: also your switch should test for, planet not newWeight

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have your `weight` and `newWeight` variables swapped around.

First, you're trying to switch on `newWeight` which hasn't had a value set yet, then you are doing `(3.724 / 9.8) * weight = newWeight` which doesn't make sense at all.

I think you want to switch on `planet` and then set `newWeight` using

`newWeight = (3.724 / 9.8) * weight;`

As for the error on the last line of code, it is happening because if the number 1 to 9 isn't entered, newWeight is null. You can either add a default case, or initialize all your variables to 0, like so:

```
int planet = 0;
double weight = 0.00, newWeight = 0.00;
```

Comment: Ok, I switched them around but I am still getting an error at the " * weight". Now it is saying "incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int"

Comment: ok I got it but now my final line of code says "variable newWeight might not have been initialized"....

Comment: the final line is: "System.out.print("On " + planet + ", your new weight is: " + newWeight);"  and the error is "variable newWeight might not have been initialized"

Answer (score 1):

your assignment to variable newWeight is wrong!

you should fix to:

```
newWeight = ( ... ) * weight; break;

IE. case 1: newWeight = (3.724 / 9.8) * weight; break;
```

In java the variable that will receive the value MUST be at the left side of the operator `equal ( = )`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `newWeight` should be `Integer` which corresponding to `case` of switch branch .

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit more wrong here than the other answers have mentioned:

1. You've declared `weight` as a `double` but you are assigning it with the code `input.nextInt()`. Should that be `input.nextDouble()`?
2. As other answers: your `switch` should be on `planet`, ie `switch(planet)`
3. As other answers, your `newWeight` assignment is back to front, eg `newweight = (3.724 / 9.8) * weight`
4. You haven't captured a case where the user entered any other number for planet.
5. You need a default case to ensure all your desired variables have been appropriately set. Your Editor might warn you about this possibility, `default: newweight = 0`

Answer (score 1):

OK you guys ROCK!!! got everything working properly, except the name of the planet won't come through. Instead, it shows their numeric selection of the planet that corresponds with that number. But I will figure that out. Thank you guys so much for your help! If anyone wants to know what their weight is on another planet, here's the finished code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double weight;
    double newWeight;
    int planet;

    System.out.println("1. Mercury");
    System.out.println("2. Venus");
    System.out.println("3. Earth");
    System.out.println("4. Mars");
    System.out.println("5. Jupiter");
    System.out.println("6. Saturn");
    System.out.println("7. Uranus");
    System.out.println("8. Neptune");
    System.out.println("9. Pluto");
    System.out.println("                   ");
    System.out.println("Select a planet from above: ");
    planet = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your weight in pounds: ");
    weight = input.nextDouble();

    switch(planet) {
        default: newWeight = 0.00;
        case 1: newWeight = (3.724 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 2: newWeight = (8.918 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 3: newWeight = (9.8 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 4: newWeight = (3.724 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 5: newWeight = (24.892 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 6: newWeight = (10.584 / 9.8) * weight; break; 
        case 7: newWeight = (8.918 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 8: newWeight = (11.662 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 9: newWeight = (1.622 / 9.8) * weight; break;
    }
    System.out.print("On " + planet + ", your new weight is: " + newWeight);
}
```

}

Comment: `break;` on the default case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should initialize newWeight to be 0.

```
double newWeight = 0;
```

And like everyone said above it should be case(planet).

```
switch(planet) {
        case 1: newWeight = (3.724 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 2:  newWeight = (8.918 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 3:  newWeight = (9.8 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 4:  newWeight = (3.724 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 5:  newWeight = (24.892 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 6:  newWeight = (10.584 / 9.8) * weight; break; 
        case 7:  newWeight = (8.918 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 8:  newWeight = (11.662 / 9.8) * weight; break;
        case 9:  newWeight = (1.622 / 9.8) * weight; break;
}
```

also it would be nice to have the name of the planet in the final print statement instead of the number. Maybe put all of the names of the planets into a array. here is to get you started :)

```
    ArrayList<String> planetName = new ArrayList(){{
        add("Mercury");
        add("Venus");
        add("Earth");
        add("Mars");
        add("Jupiter");
        add("Saturn");
        add("Uranus");
        add("Neptune");
        add("Pluto");
    }
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < planetName.size(); i++){
        System.out.println((i+1) + ". "+ planetName.get(i)  );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `switch(planet)`?  Otherwise you'd need to switch on arbitrary weights.

Answer (score 0):

You placed the incorrect variable in the `switch` statements, and your assignment `operators` are reversed.

```
switch(planet) {
    case 1: newWeight = (3.724 / 9.8) * weight; break;
    //....
}
```